# Merging two Dictionaries without overwrite values in the nested one

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, mergeddictionaries

I tried to update main dictionary with every new one in the loop, but every time it overwrite values inside the nested dictionary.
I mean I want smth like this:

```
{'Barbour': {1900: 73041, 1910: 895427, 1920: 1531624, 1930: 1617086, 1940: 1420561, 1950: 1853223, 
             1960: 3092728, 1970: 3505193, 1980: 3659797, 1990: 2575561, 2000: 743757, 2010: 1730711}, 
'Berkeley': {1900: 0, 1910: 0, 1920: 0, 1930: 0, 1940: 0, 1950: 0, 1960: 0, 1970: 0, 1980: 0, 1990: 
          0, 2000: 0, 2010: 0}}
```

(for all of the cities)

```
def read_file_contents_coal():
    return ['Barbour,73041,895427,1531624,1617086,1420561,1853223,3092728,3505193,3659797,2575561,743757,1730711\n',
            'Berkeley,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n',
            'Boone,0,50566,1477560,3045056,3804527,5851267,6278609,11607216,13842525,27618152,32446186,23277998\n',
            'Braxton,0,114422,286955,123991,13751,38414,218087,0,459517,3256906,1196489,439662\n',
            ]

def process_file_contents():
    lst = read_file_contents_coal()
    dic = {}
    coal_dic = {}
    yearcoaldic = {}
    ycdic = {}
    for stringdata in lst:
        city_data = stringdata.strip().split(',')
        year = 1900
        for j in range(1, 13):
            ycdic = {year: int(city_data[j])}
            year += 10
            yearcoaldic.update(ycdic)
        dic = {city_data[0]: yearcoaldic}

    coal_dic.update(dic)
    print(coal_dic)
    return coal_dic
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]**: the issue is that you have to move `yearcoaldic` to the first loop and always set it to en empty dictionary otherwise you will always overwrite your values as you have experienced.

```py
def process_file_contents():
    lst = read_file_contents_coal()
    dic = {}
    coal_dic = {}
    ycdic = {}
    for stringdata in lst:
        yearcoaldic = {}
        city_data = stringdata.strip().split(',')
        year = 1900
        for j in range(1, 13):
            ycdic = {year: int(city_data[j])}
            year += 10
            yearcoaldic.update(ycdic)
        # dic = {city_data[0]: yearcoaldic}
        dic[city_data[0]] = yearcoaldic

    # coal_dic.update(dic)
    # print(coal_dic)
    return dic
```

Comment: When I tried like this, every city got values of the last added city ;/ It is the same issue as I have with my previous code. Anyway Thanks for help <3 <3

Comment: I mean at the end, when programs executed, every city got nested dictionary with years ofc and those years got the same values for every city, same values of the last city I added.Every city got this beginning {1900: 0, 1910: 0, 1920: 1270782,

Comment: My bad, correcting the issue, you have always initialize `yearcoaldic` to an empty dictionary otherwise you will always rewrite it as you have experienced

Comment: Oh yeah, perfectly working as I want to <3 big thanks <3 Have a good day!